# MVC 4 - Centralize the create action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'll try to be clear. I'm developing a web application based on MVC 4 and Entity Framework. Through this app, I can create some **Products** which is depending on an other table which is **Product Types** As you can see, in my create product View, I have a dropdownlist which contains the product types :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>
    Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Purchase date :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { @class = "datepicker"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Serial number :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SerialNumber, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Product type :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductType", String.Empty)<a href="../ProductType/Create">Add
                a new product type?</a>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_ProductType)
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And in my create product type View, I have a dropdownlist of existing product companies (so the same relation which exists between product and product type :

```
@model BuSIMaterial.Models.ProductType

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProductType</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Model : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Model, new { maxlength = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Catalog Price : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CatalogPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatalogPrice)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Company : 
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Id_ProductCompany", String.Empty)<a href ="../ProductCompany/Create" >Add a new company?</a>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id_ProductCompany)
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

What I tried is to "mix" these 2 views in one **Create Product View**. So I think my action will change a little bit. Also, I think I'll have to do 2 adds in my database. Is it the best way to do what I want?

**UPDATE** : by using a viewmodel, I got this :

My View Model :

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

My Create Action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateFullProduct(ProductViewModel pvm)
{
    ViewBag.Id_ProductCompany = new SelectList(db.ProductCompanies, "Id_ProductCompany", "Name", pvm.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Product product = new Product { PurchaseDate = pvm.Product.PurchaseDate, 
                                        SerialNumber = pvm.Product.SerialNumber,
                                        Id_ProductType = pvm.ProductType.Id_ProductType};

        ProductType productType = new ProductType {Model = pvm.ProductType.Model,
                                                   CatalogPrice = pvm.ProductType.CatalogPrice,
                                                   Id_ProductCompany = pvm.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany};

        db.ProductTypes.AddObject(productType);
        db.Products.AddObject(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Person");       

    }

    return View(pvm);
}
```

When I try to save the new entries, I got this issue : `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_bm_ProductTypes_bm_ProductCompanies".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Products` are "**dependent**" on `ProductTypes`, merging them into one is a good idea. You'll have to merge the post action too, which will have 2 inserts into your database (which is correct, one for `Product`, one for `ProductType`.

You'll have to put them both in one Model too so you can use it in your view, something like:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT: Your problem with your saving is because the ProductComany is not being posted (as indiciated in Chat)**

To fix that, first we'll put the values for the Dropdown in the model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ProductCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate it in your `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` by doing:

```
model.ProductCompanies = db.ProductCompanies
    .ToList()
    .Select(s => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = s.Name,
        Value = s.Id.ToString()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductType.Id_ProductCompany, Model.ProductCompanies)
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your fast answer, I'll try it right now and let you know.

Comment: So I did what you say and I think I'm on the right way. I'll update my post.

Comment: @Traffy Cool, what exactly are you updating your post to contain?

Comment: The action which is supposed to add in my database. Unfortunately I have an error while inserting in the db.

Comment: @Traffy Sure, what is ProductCompanies? Should you be adding that as well?

Comment: ProductCompanies is a table with only one field (Name) and my ProductTypes table is depending on this table (so when I created a product type, I have to choose in a dropdown list a company). I hope it is clear.

Comment: You need to create that ProductCompanies record for the selected type. It looks like you're trying to created a ProductType with a ProductCompany that doesn't exist.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28430/discussion-between-traffy-and-mattytommo)

Comment: The value selected in the dropdown ProductCompany is not being sent back to your controller.